# Constructor recognition in WebStorm (Node)

Tags: node.js, webstorm

Very new to node development. I'm trying to define ES6 classes in WebStorm for a node application, but WebStorm doesn't seem to recognize the **constructor** keyword.  Instead, it greys the word out, puts an "error squiggly" underneath it and tells me "Unused method constructor".

Am I doing something wrong? This seems like pretty simple functionality that should be supported.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: which version of WebStorm are you using?

Comment: I still have the same in IDEA, you could try filing an issue here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues - they are usually pretty responsive with fixes.

Answer (score 3):

You will have to enable Javascript `ECMA6` syntax support for it otherwise Webstorm will not recognize the new es6 keywords.

To enable ECMA6 support in webstorm , first click on the "**File**" menu on the top right hand corner. Then choose "**Settings**". After which a big settings panel should appear, navigate to "**Language & Framework**" and select Javascript. On your left handside screen now select "**ECMA6**" as the Java language version and hit "apply" at the bottom right.

**Example:**
[image: Webstorm settings panel]

**Output:**

[image: showing es6 syntax]

Comment: Thanks for the help! I've done that (set JavaScript language version to ECMAScript 6 that is) and the code runs perfectly well, I get no other ES6-related warnings.  It just still won't recognize constructors (link to screenshot added above).

Comment: @davidlav: I"m having the same issue. Any solution?

Comment: @mags I'm not certain, but I think the reason might be that Webstorm hasn't yet detected that the class has been instantiated, in which case the "Unused method constructor" warning actually makes pretty good sense. Try instantiating it in another file on your project and see if that rectifies it.